# How to change background color randomly every second programmatically in Kotlin for Android

Tags: android, kotlin, colors

I am working on my little Android project where the requirement is to change background color randomly every second. There is any way to do this?

Please prefer the kotlin language because I'm a beginner in development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy but tricky.
I am using the handler Runnable method to trigger every second random function and create a new color.
you can do like this :

````
val colorUpdater = object:Runnable {
  public override fun run() {
    val random = Random()
    val color = Color.argb(255, random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256))
    backgroundLayout.setBackgroundcolor(color)
    handler.postDelayed(colorUpdater, 1000)
  }
}
handler.post(colorUpdater)```
````

Comment: You should also add a Check of Active lifecycle too otherrwise it will crash . For instance in activity you can put `if(!isFinishing())` and in fragment you can use `if(isAdded())` inside `Runnable`.

Comment: @ADM Exactly! don't forget to call `handler.removeCallbacks(colorUpdater)`  in onStop() method and also call `handler.post(colorUpdater)` in onStart() method.